# Mouse Hover effect runs on each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have 5 occurence of UL on a single page. So , when i mouse-over one image then the same effect runs of every instance of UL(i.e. it changes the HTML of all 5 occurences).

I want to execute the script on individual UL so that the effect runs on the respective UL where i mouse-hover instead of all of them.

Live code example : http://jsfiddle.net/5FPSc/

Thanks in advance. Any help / pointer would be of great help. / GSA

HTML :

```
<ul class="answerOptions">
    <li data-score="0" data-answer="A" class="answer-1">
      <figure><img src="assets/images/styles/quiz/ques2_A.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <figcaption>Dinner and a movie</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li data-score="1" data-answer="B" class="answer-2">
      <figure><img src="assets/images/styles/quiz/ques2_B.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <figcaption>2 words: Laser Tag</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li data-score="0" data-answer="C" class="answer-3">
      <figure><img src="assets/images/styles/quiz/ques2_C.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <figcaption>Stroll through the park and a picnic</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li data-score="0" data-answer="D" class="answer-4">
      <figure><img src="assets/images/styles/quiz/ques2_D.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <figcaption>Skydiving</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li data-score="4" data-answer="E" class="answer-5">
      <figure><img src="assets/images/styles/quiz/ques2_E.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <figcaption>Art gallery and wine tasting</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </li>
</ul>
    <div class="answerItem-1"></div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
$('.answerOptions figure').hover(function(){
    $(".answerItem-1").html($(this).find("figcaption").html());
},function(){
if($('figure').hasClass('selected') != true){
    $(".answerItem-1").html("");
}
else {
      $(".answerItem-1").html($("figure.selected").find("figcaption").html());
}
}); 
$('.answerOptions figure').click(function(){    
    $('figure').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");   
    $(".answerItem-1").html($(this).find("figcaption").html());
});
```

Comment: i dont get it, you want it to also have an effect on all of them at the same time?

Comment: @iight  no, i want to highlight one answer at a time for particular UL. If you see jsFiddle link, it is showing both options on the mouseover of available figure element.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use class, use Id. class hover efects runs on all items, id can be only one on page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are all "popping up" is because of this line: `$(".answerItem-1")` you're selecting EACH and every `.answerItem-1` and you have a bunch of those. 
You'd need to set unique identifiers. I would do something like this:

```
<figure rel="q1">
...
<div id="q1" class="answerItem-1"></div>

//jquery code
var q = $(this).attr('rel');  
$('#'+q).html($(this).find("figcaption").html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FPSc/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use objective concept, that make the LI tag has own event handler.
Just take a look to below scripts and kindly be a reference to your codes.

```
$('ul.answerOptions').delegate('li.answer-1', 'hover', function(event) {

    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        console.log('inbound');
        var $target = $(this).parents('div.question').find('div.answerItem-1');
        var showText = '';
        showText = $(this).find('figcaption').html();
        $target.html(showText);
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        var $target = $(this).parents('div.question').find('div.answerItem-1');
        $target.html('');
    }
});​
```